# Configuring the Atlassian JIRA plugin to work with Jenkins CI system

Tags: hudson, jira, jenkins, jira-plugin

I am trying to configure the JIRA plugin with Jenkins but I am receiving the error

"This is a valid URL but it doesn't look like JIRA".

I am trying to connect to my company installation of JIRA studio which is http://[company].jira.com and I know this URL is correct as I have several projects using it successfully. Is there some setting I should enable in JIRA studio for this to work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a similar issue and fixed it by setting our JIRA studio Title to "Atlassian JIRA".
You can change it by going to admin->general->account->account name->(change)

The plugin looks for one (or both) of those words, I forget which.

You might also have to enable "Accept Remote API Calls" in admin->issues->global settings->general configuration->options

Hope that works for you.

Comment: Yep I eventually found this - asked in the irc #jenkins channel on freenode IRC but thanks too :) This is such a silly bug which has been around for so long.

Comment: Thanks! I had to check out the source just because it sounded so incredible, but sure enough, there it was... Gah! Eight hours of my life I won't be getting back.