# How to configure project in Hudson/Jenkins to report to Jira

Tags: hudson, jenkins, jira, configure

I have installed and configured this plugin:

```
http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/JIRA+Plugin
```

In `Jira` I have turned `ON` option `"accept api calls"`

in Jira logs i can see that Hudson established connection

but nothing else happens, ive got test builds and they're failing but hudson doesnt report anything to jira

how to name job? how to name tests? do i need jiraID?

how to create issue that works with hudson?

how to actually tie hudson job with jira issue?

Comment: Perhaps the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585632/configuring-the-atlassian-jira-plugin-to-work-with-jenkins-ci-system) will be of assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use this plugin: [Marvelution JIRA Hudson Integration](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/11181). With it I hope yo could solve your problem.

You have to install 2 different parts of the plugin, one in JIRA and another one in Jenkins (it enables a new API to allow JIRA to connect with Jenkins).
Then, you have to go to JIRA Administration, Hudson, Servers, Add Server, configure there your Jenkins server. 
After that, go to Administration, Hudson, Associations, Add a Hudson Association and link your project in JIRA with your Jenkins task (a list of tasks will be shown).
Finally, you only have to go to your JIRA project's page and you'll see a Hudson tab in which you can see the integration that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins cannot resolve Jira issues.  It only can post comments.
Also Jenkins does not post comments in  Jira issues named as tests or jobs or anything
in scans comments in commit to svn and if there is a Jira id then after build it posts comment.
This is too poor and basic functionality for me so I gave up.

I recently found this plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jira+Issue+Updater+Plugin
but I'm in the middle of a project and dont want do test it now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create issues in Jira from e.g. failed tests in Jenkins, then the JiraTestResultReporter plugin will help you. See this [link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JiraTestResultReporter-plugin).

Answer (score 0):

I am currently attempting to integrate Jenkins (version 1.53+) with JIRA (v5.2) to have the i) create jira issue and ii) update jira issue capabilities. My source control is SVN and my user is configured with CROWD

Currently, I am able to only update a JIRA issue from a post-build. The key is to have the latest SVN commit message begin with '-' as the format (i.e. 'PROJECT-3' denotes issue number 3 for jira project key = PROJECT)

See the overall plugin and configuration process at this link: http://blog.dominikschadow.de/?p=313

output of jenkins updates the JIRA issue (referenced in the svn commit message as I indicated) with:i) STATUS ii)jenkins job output link iii) svn commit message and file(s) changes / removed.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to create a JIRA from a build step? A workaround maybe?