# JIRA is not able to configure application URL of Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jira

I am getting error while integrating jenkins with JIRA.
Both JIRA and jenkins are hosted on same server.
Provided application URL in JIRA is my-ip:8080

> error: No response was received from the URL you entered - it may not be valid. Please fix the URL below, if needed, and click Continue.

Comment: did you try `http://localhost:8080`?

Comment: yes..i have already tried that.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "integration Jenkins with JIRA". Explain at least what you have installed  in JIRA and Jenkins (additionally), and what your configuration is. Then describe the steps you are doing, which lead to the error message (and where). At the moment, it is all guess-work ...

Comment: I have installed add-on for jenkins in JIRA. Followed steps in JIRA
1.Go to Manage Add-on
2.Select Application Links in the left panel. The "Configure   Application Links" page opens.
3.enter the URL of the Jenkins server and then select Create new link.
Here i am getting error described above.

Answer (score 0):

What ports are JIRA & Jenkins running on? Usually JIRA and Jenkins like to run on the same port (8080) by default. You can change the default port for starting Jenkins as ala something like java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090

Did you see this link: [Configuring the Atlassian JIRA plugin to work with Jenkins CI system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585632/configuring-the-atlassian-jira-plugin-to-work-with-jenkins-ci-system?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks Brooke, but my both application is running on different port one is on 8080 and other one is on 8888. so it might not be a problem.

Comment: Wait - which way are you trying to do the integration? I *assume* you're hoping to have Jenkins tag JIRA issues with build manifest/status?

Comment: Yes i have already gone through that link and have enabled remote API service in jira. i have my scripts and results and i want to update issue status in jira accordingly using jira test reporter plugin available in jenkins. I am not sure but i think there should be jira-jenkins link configuration to do that. let me know in case of my incorrect way.